# Need to shift the child nodes in json to parent node

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have the following JSON -

```
[{ 
 "ctin":"guju3j3jgjh3b",
 "inv":[ 
  { 
     "inum":"OS1920/16060",
     "idt":"01-08-2019",
     "val":17000.00,
     "pos":"20",
     "rchrg":"N"
  }, { 
     "inum":"OS1920/16066",
     "idt":"02-08-2019",
     "val":17602.00,
     "pos":"29",
     "rchrg":"N"
  }
 ]
},{ 
 "ctin":"guj324djgjh3b",
 "inv":[ 
  { 
     "inum":"OS1920/16064",
     "idt":"03-08-2019",
     "val":19125.00,
     "pos":"26",
     "rchrg":"N"
  }
 ]
}
.
.
.
]
```

I need to combine the child and the parent node.
So that the result will come as following -

```
[{ 
 "ctin":"guju3j3jgjh3b",
 "inum":"OS1920/16060",
 "idt":"01-08-2019",
 "val":17000.00,
 "pos":"20",
 "rchrg":"N"
}, { 
 "ctin":"guju3j3jgjh3b",
 "inum":"OS1920/16066",
 "idt":"02-08-2019",
 "val":17602.00,
 "pos":"29",
 "rchrg":"N"
}, { 
 "ctin":"guj324djgjh3b",
 "inum":"OS1920/16064",
 "idt":"03-08-2019",
 "val":19124,
 "pos":"26",
 "rchrg":"N"
},
.
.
.
]
```

Tried searching SO, but no luck.

Also, tried removing the "INV" node, but no luck. It just goes [object object] in Angular due to the looping of nodes inside one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using `map` function and `concat`:

```
const data = [{
  "ctin":"guju3j3jgjh3b",
  "inv":[
   {
      "inum":"OS1920/16060",
      "idt":"01-08-2019",
      "val":17000.00,
      "pos":"20",
      "rchrg":"N"
   }, {
      "inum":"OS1920/16066",
      "idt":"02-08-2019",
      "val":17602.00,
      "pos":"29",
      "rchrg":"N"
   }
  ]
 },{
  "ctin":"guj324djgjh3b",
  "inv":[
   {
      "inum":"OS1920/16064",
      "idt":"03-08-2019",
      "val":19125.00,
      "pos":"26",
      "rchrg":"N"
   }
  ]
 }
];
```

and code is:

```
let notFlattened = data.map(({ctin, inv}) => {
    inv = inv.map(r=> {
          r.ctin = ctin;
          return r;
      });
    return inv;
})
let merged = [].concat.apply([], notFlattened);

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only assume that the JSON is an array. You can use a combination of the `.map`, `.reduce` and `.concat` methods of Array to get what you want:

```
const result = data
  .map((item) => item.inv.map((inv) => ({ ctin: item.ctin, ...inv })))
  .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
```

Comment: Or just `.flatMap`.

Comment: @VLAZ i won't recommend that yet, until it is supported by all major browsers

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

```
for (var j = 0; j < this.datasource.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.datasource1[j].inv.length; i++) {
     this.datasource[j].inv[i].ctin = this.datasource[j]["ctin"];
  }
  /* delete this.datasource[j]['ctin'];
  this.result.push(this.datasource[j].inv); */
}
```